# How can I get the connection string to a database hosted Azure in the appsettings.json file?

Tags: c#, azure-database-mysql

I have created a database and hosted it in Microsoft Azure. I am struggle to connect to the database because I do not have the connection. Where can I get the connection string?

I have tired to find the connection on the Azure platform under the Azure databases that I have created and I was expecting to be able to access the data stored in the database.

Comment: In your SQL Database blade, go to Overview and there should be a connection string link you can click under essentials.

Answer (score 0):

*Connect to Azure and create an SQL Server and database.*

1. *Select the connection string of that particular database in the left pane as shown below and choose connection strings as highlighted .

[image]

2. *The below highlighted string need to be used in the `appsettings.json` to communicate with database of the azure.*
   [image]
3. *Use the connection string in the `appsettings.json`file as shown below.

[image]